# Pasar un string a función javascript desde php

Tags: php, php7

Tengo este código php:

```
$enlace = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='getComentarios('cadena de texto')'>".$gasto["comentarios"]."</a>";
```

Me tira un error y no me esta pasando la cadena ya he hecho miles de intentos y no tengo exito, como podría solucionar esto??

Gracias a la ayuda que estoy recibiendo por parte de @phpMyGuel ahora el código ha quedado así:

```
$enlace = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getComentarios(\'cadena de texto\')">'.$gasto["comentarios"].'</a>';
```

El problema ahora viene en lo siguiente, necesito pasar a la función javascript el valor de una variable string y he puesto el código así pero marca error:

```
$enlace = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getComentarios(\'$gasto["comentarios"]\')">'.$gasto["comentarios"].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En **PHP** el caracter de escape es **/**. En tu cadena, podemos usarlo para usar comillas simples sin que estas rompan la concatenación:

**PHP**

```
$gasto["comentarios"]  = 'PRUEBA';

$enlace = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getComentarios(\'cadena de texto\')">' . $gasto["comentarios"] . '</a>';

print $enlace;
```

**SALIDA:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getComentarios('cadena de texto')">PRUEBA</a>
```

**EDIT**

Lo más sencillo para hacer que la función `onClick` reciba correctamente el valor de una variable sería separar la concatenación, como en el caso de lo que se muestra dentro del enlace:

```
 $enlace = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getComentarios(\'' . $gasto["comentarios"] . '\')">' . $gasto["comentarios"] . '</a>';
```

Comment: Me sigue tirando error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Perdón, tenía un error en mi código. Ya está resuelto ^^

Comment: Sigue tirando el mismo error

Comment: No sé si estoy espeso o que está pasando. He testeado el código para asegurarme de que funciona. Actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta con tu nueva respuesta por favor revisala por que surge otra duda ahora pasando el valor de una variable string

Comment: Editada mi respuesta para contemplar el caso que mencionas.